# Trying to catch db result as json in jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I'm trying to use jquery to get some updated data from the database, when a user clicks on a checkbox.

The checkbox is like this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="r571" value="1" '. $checked . $disabled .' id="check_kredit" onClick="ds.r571a.value=this.checked ? \''.date('d-m-Y').'\' : \'\';">'; ?>
```

The ajax is like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#check_kredit").click(function() {                
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "getkredit.php?k=129",             
        dataType: "json",   //expect json to be returned                
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            //alert(response);
            //$("#kreHint").html(response); 
            //console.log("sfsd");
            //console.log(response);
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});
```

And the call (getkredit.php) to the database is:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
$k = intval($_GET['k']);


if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
 }



$kid = "SELECT * FROM kunde WHERE id = '".$k."'";
$rkid = mysql_query($kid) or die(mysql_error);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rkid)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}
mysql_close($con);
```

If I running the php file directly in the browser, it returns this:

```
{
  "id": "129",
  "kundenr": "00000001",
  "hra": "",
  "navn1": "firmanavn",
  "navn2": "",
  "cvr": "142570220805205",
  "adresse1": "Et vejnavn",
  "adresse2": "",
  "postland": null,
  "postnr": "",
  "postby": "Et sted i DK",
  "land": "DK",
  "tlf": "00000000",
  "fax": "00000000",
  "telex": "",
  "www": "",
  "email": "",
  "att": "Hans Nielsen, Gunner Nu Hansen",
  "note": "Faktura skal p\u00e5f\u00f8res f\u00f8lgende: Sagsnr-afdelingsnr-art-evt. valgfri",
  "betal": "Netto kontant, 8 dage",
  "sikker": "Beh\u00f8rig kreditvurdering",
  "kundegruppe": "Entrepren\u00f8r",
  "ansvarlig": "",
  "opret": "2005-01-20 13:07:44",
  "rettet": "2011-08-29 09:59:24",
  "ejer_id": "129",
  "x-factor": "100",
  "kreditmax": "0",
  "kreditbelastning": "0"
}
```

But when I run it through the ajax call, it returns html code.

That puzzles my, but since this is maybe the second time, I'm working with ajax, it's all very new to me. So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending the `Content-Type` header as @Michiel suggested in answer? And why echoing out one row in while loop as it can have more rows?

Comment: Yeap, at the top of the getkredit.php file I have header('Content-Type: application/json', true); At the testing time, I only need one output, but may need multiple later on, hence the while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed the url to be like this instead: 
`url: "\getkredit.php?k=129"

Answer (score 0):

Update your ajax call to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#check_kredit").click(function() {                
          $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "getkredit.php?k=129",             
            dataType: "json",   
            headers: {         
                       Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
                       "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"  
                     },               
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                //json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                //alert(response);
                //$("#kreHint").html(response); 
                //console.log("sfsd");
                //console.log(response);
                //alert(response);
            }

        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: I don't know if that helps, because somehow it doesn't return anything at all now. :-(

Comment: No, at least not a new one. Got one, but that has nothing to do with this.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. I don't get any data out in the console. But found out that, if I change datatype to html, it'll return the same html code, I was talking about earliere. But when I change it back to json, I get no output in the console.

Comment: Okay, gotten a step closer, as it says it's invalid json. Somehow it still returns html page instead of json. And it didn't help putting in the headset

Comment: Maybe the json you’re returning is not valid.

Comment: It isn’t but hos do I make it valid? Shouldn’t json_encode make it valid